# How do I make bevel equal on both sides of the edge?

Tags: bevel

I am new to Blender and learning little as I go. I notice that when I bevel on a cube's edge with n-segments, the effect is a nice even bevel (quarter circle). However, if I make a rectangle (as shown on the picture) the bevel is longer on the longest face and almost non-existent on the shorter face. Is there a way to make a nice round bevel that creates quarter circle on the edge? I would like to make a rounded rectangle.
Thanks.

[image: Bevel edge on rectangle]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7298/why-is-it-important-to-apply-transformation-to-an-objects-data

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because your object has non-uniform scale.

First, go to the **object mode**. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> -> **Rotation & scale** (object-apply)

Then try again